# Update Salesforce records from .Net(c#) based on SQL query

Tags: apex, api, class, c#

I need to update some Salesforce records from .Net(c#) based on the SQL query.  Below is my table (vendors in sql). I need to update Salesforce Object(NRProducts__c) with the data in the SQL.

```
  The SQL table vendors has the following columns:

      Id                 Amazon_Listing_Level     Amazon_Rule_ID     ESTShipPrice 
  a0C4000000DKIlj                    15                   102           2.25
  a0C4000000DKkhy                    1                    222           5.36
  a0C4000000DKIdr                    10                   562           10.25
  a0C4000000Djjut                    20                   521           8.00
```

I was having some issues passing the last 2 values which are not String in Salesforce. 
 Here is the code, I hope you find it useful!

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Updating Salesforce
        sforce.SforceService service = new sforce.SforceService();
        sforce.LoginResult lr = service.login("username", "passw+token");
        service.Url = lr.serverUrl;
        service.SessionHeaderValue = new sforce.SessionHeader();
        service.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId = lr.sessionId;



        //SQL Query
        String queryString = "Select id, Amazon_Listing_Level__c, Amazon_Rule__ID__c, ESTShipPrice__c from vendors2";
        SqlDataReader dr = classdb.LoadReader(queryString) as SqlDataReader;

        sforce.NRProducts__c nrProduct = new sforce.NRProducts__c();
                while (dr.Read())
                {

                nrProduct.Id = dr[0].ToString();
                nrProduct.Amazon_Listing_Level__c = dr[1].ToString();

     //Here is the problem I could not pass these 2 values to salesforce
     //nrProduct.Amazon_Rule_ID__c is type Number(4,0)in SF
     //nrProduct.ESTShipPrice__c is type Currency(16, 2) in SF

                nrProduct.Amazon_Rule_ID__c = Convert.ToInt32(dr[2]);
                nrProduct.Amazon_Rule_ID__cSpecified = true;
                nrProduct.ESTShipPrice__c = Convert.ToDouble(dr[3]);
                nrProduct.ESTShipPrice__cSpecified = true;



                }
                sforce.SaveResult[] update_result = service.update(new sforce.sObject[] { nrProduct });

                dr.Close(); 


                }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have already got the salesforce ID's in your SQL database, I think you just need to create instances for each record you need to update and fire off an update:

```
List <sforce.NRProducts__c> nrProductsToUpdate = new List <sforce.NRProducts__c> ();

while (dr.Read())
{
    sforce.NRProducts__c nrProduct = new sforce.NRProducts__c ();
    nrProduct.Id = dr.GetString(0);
    nrProduct.Amazon_Listing_Level__c = dr.GetString(1);
    nrProduct.Amazon_Rule_ID__c = dr.GetString(2);
    nrProduct.ESTShipPrice__c = dr.GetString(3);
    nrProductsToUpdate.Add(nrProduct);
}

sforce.SaveResult[] update_result = service.update(nrProductsToUpdate);
```

The above code might not work, I just typed it to give you an idea, haven't actually tested it. Let me know how you go.

I have updated my code but I am having some issues passing the last 2 values which are not String in Salesforce. any ideas?

```
   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Updating Salesforce
        sforce.SforceService service = new sforce.SforceService();
        sforce.LoginResult lr = service.login("username", "passw+token");
        service.Url = lr.serverUrl;
        service.SessionHeaderValue = new sforce.SessionHeader();
        service.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId = lr.sessionId;

        //create list
       // List<sforce.sObject> nrProductsToUpdate = new List<sforce.sObject>();
        //SQL Query
        String queryString = "Select id, Amazon_Listing_Level__c, Amazon_Rule__ID__c, ESTShipPrice__c from vendors2";
        SqlDataReader dr = classdb.LoadReader(queryString) as SqlDataReader;

        sforce.NRProducts__c nrProduct = new sforce.NRProducts__c();
                while (dr.Read())
                {

                nrProduct.Id = dr[0].ToString();
                nrProduct.Amazon_Listing_Level__c = dr[1].ToString();

     //Here is the problem I can not pass these 2 values to salesforce
     //nrProduct.Amazon_Rule_ID__c is type Number(4,0)in SF
     //nrProduct.ESTShipPrice__c is type Currency(16, 2) in SF

                nrProduct.Amazon_Rule_ID__c = Convert.ToInt32(dr[2]);
                nrProduct.ESTShipPrice__c = Convert.ToDouble(dr[3]);



                }
                sforce.SaveResult[] update_result = service.update(new sforce.sObject[] { nrProduct });

                dr.Close(); 


                }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, you are always trying to help me. I will try it and let you know

Comment: Bachovski, I have changed the code, but there is an error in the saveResult part, and if I try the following approach error: cannot convert list to salesforce object                                                                  sforce.SaveResult[] update_result = service.update(new sforce.sObject[] { nrProductsToUpdate });

Comment: Try changing this `List<sforce.NRProducts__c> nrProductsToUpdate = new List<sforce.NRProducts__c>();` to `List<sforce.sObject> nrProductsToUpdate = new List<sforce.sObject>();`. Then instead of `service.update(new sforce.sObject[] { nrProductsToUpdate })` you should use `service.update(nrProductsToUpdate)` because the list is already initialised.

Comment: Bachovski, I made the changes but in the code below I am getting an error: Error  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<SanboxUpdateAPI.sforce.sObject>' to 'SanboxUpdateAPI.sforce.sObject[]' sforce.SaveResult[] update_result = service.update(nrProductsToUpdate );

Comment: i added a gridview.dataSource=nrProductsToUpdate  to see what is in the list and it is just displaying the column 'id'

Comment: Then that means you don't have the values stored in the SQL database or you're not retrieving the information correctly.

Comment: And for the issue above, I am not an expert, only done 1 or 2 integrations and can't recall the syntax exactly in C# but something like `sforce.sObject[] nrProductsToUpdate = new sforce.sObject[]` should create and initialise the list and then you need to add all your objects in this list and do a single update. I will try to find out the correct syntax in the meantime...

Comment: I think I am not retrieving the data correctly, because I hardcoded the sql table values

Comment: I think I found the solution but now I am facing another problem, just the value String(Amazon_Listing_Level__c) is passing to salesforce and the other 2 that need convertion are not passing. I will update the question with the problem

Comment: Are you getting any errors or the values are not getting through?

Comment: they are not getting through, I tested them independently and only the string one passed

Comment: Try adding `fieldname__cspecified = true;` for each of the fields after you assign the values. E.g. `nrProduct.Amazon_Rule_ID__cspecified = true;`

Comment: Man, you made it... that works. Thank you thank you so much. You have no idea how much appreciate your help!

Comment: All good, I'm glad you solved the problem. I still haven't figured out why that 'specified' is required, but took me ages the first time to find out :)

Comment: Bachovski, I am glad you did:) I am testing the values and I found a small problem, for some reason just the second record of the SQL table vendors is passing to Salesforce and the other  no. But I will try tomorrow it's getting late here i will let you know the outcome. Thanks again! have a good day!

Comment: ok I fixed it the saveResult[] has to be inside the while{}. Officially working!

Comment: Nice one! Once you get this going, everything else is pretty much the same....

Answer (score 2):

**PS** The answer below related to the original version of the question. Though the code changes should in my opinion be made in any case (particularly as the error reporting may reveal the underyling problem), they do not address the specifics of the later versions of the question.

---

You are not clear on what problem you have: a compilation problem or a runtime-problem. You should supplement your question with that information.

Working without that context I have two suggestions:

1. The update call should probably be done outside the loop after all the data has been changed
2. You should check the update results

I'm afraid I can't comment about the specifics of C# syntax (except to say that it would probably be better to use foreach) and what I have below may be syntactically wrong but hopefully it illustrates the above two points:

```
sforce.QueryResult query = service.query("SELECT NRCode__c FROM NRProducts__c ");
if (query.records != null && query.records.Length > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < query.records.Length; i++) {
        sforce.NRProducts__c updateAccount = query.records[i] as sforce.NRProducts__c;
        updateAccount.Amazon_Listing_Level__c = "  ";
        updateAccount.Amazon_Rule_ID__c = " ";
        updateAccount.ESTShipPrice__c = " ";
    }
    Label2.Text = "";
    sforce.SaveResult[] results = service.update(query.records);
    for (int i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        sforce.SaveResult r = results[i];
        if (!r.success) {
            for (int j = 0; j < r.errors.length; j++) {
                Label2.Text += r.errors[j].message + " ";
            }
        }
    }
    if (Label2.Text == "") {
        Label2.Text = "records updated successfully";
    }
} else {
    Label2.Text = "no records found ";
}
```

Comment: keith, I will edit my question with what am trying to accomplish here. Thank you.

Comment: @Carlos Sounds like you are making progress. If you no longer need an answer to your original question please make that clear.

Comment: Keith, I still need help, I just edited the question so it is more clear where I need help

Comment: @Carlos OK. But personally I don't understand what "modify this code so it updates only the records of the SQL" means. Can you be clearer about that?

Comment: Ok, the NRCode that are in the SQL Table(vendors) exist in salesforce object(NRProducts__c), so if there any way I can update these NRCodes and their fields(Amazon_Listing_Level,  Amazon_Rule_ID, and      ESTShipPrice) using the api? please let me know if this is clear enough

Comment: In other words, I want to update the records that my sql query returns, NRCode is the primary key

Comment: @Carlos The primary key in Salesforce is always the ID value a 15/18 digit string. I think it is implicitly queried if you don't include it but I suggest you explicitly query it and bear it in mind in your logic. Late here so I wish you good luck.

Comment: I have updated it my question so It makes more sense what I am trying to accomplish